# G++ Not found when compiling C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

im having problems with mingw because when i want to compile c++ it says g++ not found.
Thanks for every tip and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: What OS, Windows? What version of MinGW did you install, and how exactly did you install it? Maybe you need to add your compiler's `bin` directory to the PATH?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with build-essential already installed
This worked for me:

```
 sudo apt --reinstall install g++ g++-9
```

Answer (score -1):

Get one by installing

> build-essential

package.

Typing

> sudo apt-get install build-essential

into terminal is one of the easiest ways to achieve that.

Comment: im not stupid, i have it installed

Comment: @gradyn I actually find this a really good answer to the question you asked. As you didn't specify what the situation is, it's normal that people suggest the basics first. Try asking your question in a way that it has sufficient info in order to not get a repeat of what you already did